# docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:50075

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hdp

when i try to install a sandbox-hdp version 2.6.5 by hortonworks on docker in my system by running docker-deploy-hdp256.sh script with sh command i recived the error at the end of all the pulling and some verification checksums are done.

error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:50075: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

but i could see the container with name sandbox-hdp. so i opened it and try to run hive. but it is giving some error related to connectivity.

i need to work on hive and for that i need to get this fixed.

Comment: It sounds like that port is already in use. You seem to confirm this by stating that "i could see the container with name sandbox-hdp". Try to stop and remove that container: run `docker ps` to get the container id. then run `docker stop <container id>` and `docker rm <container id>`

Comment: I removed the container and re-running the script but i find the same error after I run the script. when i tried to run 'docker ps' i could see more than one port number at the ports column for sandbox-hdp. when i see the containers in docker i can find 2 containers with sandbox-hdp and sandbox-proxy and below the proxy container i could see created and port:10000

Answer (score 0):

In this case, sometimes is hard to turn off or close a port running because some of them is used by our computer or even a range of ports is reserved randomly. So in this opportunity try to delete this port in your sandbox-proxy script because you don't need to expose all ports. Ambari-hortonworks expose a lot of ports with docker and securely you won't use all of them.
[image]